# Reduced font size of equations in align environment

Tags: equations, align, fontsize, article

When I use 'align environment' to write equations, the displayed equations (eq 1.5 & 1.6)  look smaller in font size compared to other equations (eq 1.7 & 1.8). For reference I attached screenshot of the compiled document. How to make sure all equations are of same font size?

[image]

```
\begin{align}
\pd{f}{x} &= \pd{f}{z} \cdot \pd{z}{x} = \pd{f}{z} \cdot 1 \\
\pd{f}{y} &= \pd{f}{z} \cdot \pd{z}{y} = \pd{f}{z} \cdot i
\end{align}

since $f(x) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ by \autoref{eq:complexfunction}, we also have

\begin{equation}
\pd{f}{x} = \pd{u}{x} + i \pd{v}{x} \quad \text{and} \quad \pd{f}{y} = \pd{u}{y} + i \pd{v}{y}
\end{equation}
Combining above equations, we have

\begin{equation}
\pd{f}{x} = \pd{f}{z} = \pd{u}{x} + i \pd{v}{x} \quad \text{and} \quad \pd{f}{x} = \pd{f}{z} = \pd{u}{x} + i \pd{v}{x}
\end{equation}
```

preamble (if required)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{jheppub}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{commath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {theorem}% name
  {Theorem}% title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
  {thm}% prefix

\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {definition}% name
  {Definition}% title
  {%
    colback=red!5,
    colframe=red!50!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
  {def}% prefix

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subheader{Notes}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Some Author}
\affiliation{Greatest University}
\emailAdd{author@author.com}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\flushbottom
\newpage
```

Comment: it is much easier for people to test if you post a single document that produces the output shown, rather than fragments that we have to join together, the test file needs to not use packages that are not available (jheppub) unless the problem does not occur without them, in which case a link to the package would help

Comment: possibly unrelated but I would not use `commath`

Comment: oh this is commath, is based around a misunderstanding of the `\ifinner` test, it is not really usable and accounts for the issue that you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more reasonable test document is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\begin{document}

align
\begin{align}
\pd{f}{x} &= \pd{f}{z} \cdot \pd{z}{x} = \pd{f}{z} \cdot 1 \\
\pd{f}{y} &= \pd{f}{z} \cdot \pd{z}{y} = \pd{f}{z} \cdot i
\end{align}

equation
\begin{equation}
\pd{f}{x} = \pd{u}{x} + i \pd{v}{x} \quad \text{and} \quad \pd{f}{y} = \pd{u}{y} + i \pd{v}{y}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `commath` package is based on a misunderstanding of `\ifinner` and is forcing a  text style setting in `align` The package really can not be recommended, use a simple `\frac` rather than `commath` version of `\pd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{commath}
\newcommand\pd[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\begin{document}

align
\begin{align}
\pd{f}{x} &= \pd{f}{z} \cdot \pd{z}{x} = \pd{f}{z} \cdot 1 \\
\pd{f}{y} &= \pd{f}{z} \cdot \pd{z}{y} = \pd{f}{z} \cdot i
\end{align}

equation
\begin{equation}
\pd{f}{x} = \pd{u}{x} + i \pd{v}{x} \quad \text{and} \quad \pd{f}{y} = \pd{u}{y} + i \pd{v}{y}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, may I know if it's worth using 'physics' package or does it have problems like 'commath'?

Comment: I can't say I've used either really (not my area) @147875